# Loop with in a loop

Tags: arrays, macos, matlab, loops, for-loop

Is it possible to index an array in a loop with in a loop (Matlab)? 
So I'm indexing a 3d matrix with 3 parameter:
For instance:

```
A(1,1,:)
A(1,2,:)
...
A(1,9,:)
```

then I want the code to jump to the next element of the first prameter:

```
A(2,1,:)
A(2,2,:)
...
A(2,9,:)
```

And so on until I finish with all the elements of the first parameter.

Now I have a :

```
 for j=1:27
    for i=1:9
         X(j,i,:)= f(j,i,:)   
    end
  end
```

But I'm only getting a row of results when it should be a matrix of 27x9x:
Do anyone know how to make the second loop (i) runs 9 times for the first value of j and then move to the second value of j and run 9 times i and so on? 
Thanks!

Comment: Now your code runs 9 times for `j=1`, then 9 times for `j=2` and so on. So the code is doing what you tells it to do. Can you clarify what you want to achieve? Maybe you're just implementing it wrong

Comment: How is `f` defined? We can't try to reproduce the problem unless we have the input that you're using.

Comment: Is not. It's giving me a vector of 3*9*6 @ViG

Comment: Can you give `f` as beaker says, then we can try to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

use squeeze(); something like this:

```
 for j=1:27
    for i=1:9
         tmp= squeeze(f(j,i,:));  
         X(j,i,:) = tmp;
    end
  end
```